# How can I make my iPhone 3GS icons in my app iPhone-4 savvy

Tags: iphone, interface, icons, builder, retina-display

I have a quite simple question concerning the difference in screen size between the iPhone 3/3GS and the iPhone 4. I've googled around, but was unable to come up with a good explanation.

Here's the thing: tabbar icons. All my icons are 30x30 and 60x60. I named the high resolution ones like [icon]@2x.png. When I load my app on my own iPhone 3GS, all goes fine. But when I load the app in Simulator, simulating a 4 with retina-display, the icon looks pixelated and is clearly the wrong resolution.

What am I doing wrong? These were the exact steps I followed, but I'm probably missing something. Is there something like an option I need to set in the plist?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Kind regards,

Reinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're doing it the right way. Did you try to remove the app from the simulator? Clean up the project? Re-import the icon image files?

Comment: Removing and re-importing the images did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the icons as you have and edit your plist file

The following link should help 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html

Make sure you clean and build and remove the existing application from your phone and the simulator to see the results

The complete set of icon sizes distilled is

Icon.png – Home screen icon for iPhone 3 (57×57)

Icon@2x.png – Home screen icon for iPhone 4 (114×114)

Icon-72.png – Home screen icon for iPad (72×72)

Icon-Small.png - Settings/Spotlight icon for iPhone 3 (29×29)

Icon-Small@2x.png – Settings/Spotlight icon for iPhone 4 (58×58)

Icon-Small-50.png – Spotlight icon for iPad (50×50)

iTunesArtwork – Icon for iTunes AdHoc distribution (512×512)

Comment: Are you referring to any specific setting, considering the tabbar icons, in the plist? I'm aware of the fact that the app icon must be added to the plist.

Answer (score 0):

Try (with the simulator stopped) cleaning all targets and re-building. Sometimes xcode gets dumb about what files it's got and needs to be told to clear its cached build and start fresh. It's in the "build" menu, or ctrl-shift-K.